# Ubuntu "mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware cmd interrupt" error, no SD card

Tags: 18.04, sd-card

Yesterday I did a fresh Ubuntu  install on my new mini PC (It came shipped with Win 10 Pro). The mini PC is a Belink u55.
Now I'm running into the issue that I keep seeing a lot of errors on my screen (when I plug the PC to my screen, on SSH I' dont see it). The error is as follows and keeps repeating:

```
[  196.315177] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware cmd interrupt.
[  196.319708] mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
[  196.324254] mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x00000000 | Version:  0x0000a402
[  196.328819] mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00000000 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000
[  196.333387] mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000000
[  196.337946] mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x01ff0001 | Host ctl: 0x00000001
[  196.342488] mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
[  196.347106] mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x0000a707
[  196.351659] mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x00000000 | Int stat: 0x00018000
[  196.356198] mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x00ff0003 | Sig enab: 0x00ff0003
[  196.360735] mmc0: sdhci: AC12 err:  0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000001
[  196.365272] mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x67ea64b2 | Caps_1:   0x00000000
[  196.369809] mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x00000502 | Max curr: 0x00000001
[  196.374378] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000000 | Resp[1]:  0x00000000
[  196.378934] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x00000000 | Resp[3]:  0x00000000
[  196.383456] mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x00000000
[  196.387955] mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
```

I've looked around on google and I found many people with the same Issue [AskUbuntu Topic with fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695944/sd-card-doesnt-work-well-under-ubuntu-but-does-well-under-windows), it seems to have something to do with an SD card.  However I don't have a SD card plugged in (I don't intend to use one either) and I tried the suggested fix with adding "  options sdhci debug_quirks=0x40 " inside a file, sadly this didnt work. Could anyone help me understrand the problem better and perhaps help me solve it, as I'm not nearly adept enough in linux to do this, however I would like to run Linux on my pc instead of windows for running homeassistand and other docker instances.
In one of the threads that provided a possible fix (that didnt work for me) someone asked the OP for the output of " lspci -vn " and " lsusb ", So I figured the output could be usefull so here it is:

```
root@homeserverkevin:/home/kevin# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c30e Logitech, Inc. UltraX Keyboard (Y-BL49)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

root@homeserverkevin:/home/kevin# lspci -vn
00:00.0 0600: 8086:1604 (rev 09)
        Subsystem: 8086:1604
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
        Kernel driver in use: bdw_uncore

00:02.0 0300: 8086:1616 (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: 8086:1616
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
        Memory at a9000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915

00:03.0 0403: 8086:160c (rev 09)
        Subsystem: 111e:10ec
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 50
        Memory at aa214000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:14.0 0c03: 8086:9cb1 (rev 03) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
        Subsystem: 8086:7270
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
        Memory at aa200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 0780: 8086:9cba (rev 03)
        Subsystem: 8086:7270
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
        Memory at aa21c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Kernel driver in use: mei_me
        Kernel modules: mei_me

00:1b.0 0403: 8086:9ca0 (rev 03)
        Subsystem: 8086:7270
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 49
        Memory at aa210000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 0604: 8086:9c94 (rev e3) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
        Memory behind bridge: aa100000-aa1fffff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0000000-00000000c00fffff
        Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: 8086:7270
        Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [100] #00
        Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 0604: 8086:9c96 (rev e3) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
        Memory behind bridge: aa000000-aa0fffff
        Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: 8086:7270
        Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [100] #00
        Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 0c03: 8086:9ca6 (rev 03) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
        Subsystem: 8086:7270
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
        Memory at aa21a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
        Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 0601: 8086:9cc5 (rev 03)
        Subsystem: 8086:7270
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
        Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
        Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
        Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 0106: 8086:9c83 (rev 03) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
        Subsystem: 8086:7270
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
        I/O ports at 40b0 [size=8]
        I/O ports at 40a0 [size=4]
        I/O ports at 4090 [size=8]
        I/O ports at 4080 [size=4]
        I/O ports at 4060 [size=32]
        Memory at aa219000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
        Kernel driver in use: ahci
        Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 0c05: 8086:9ca2 (rev 03)
        Subsystem: 8086:7270
        Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 255
        Memory at aa218000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        I/O ports at 4040 [size=32]
        Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 0200: 10ec:8168 (rev 0c)
        Subsystem: 10ec:0123
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
        I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
        Memory at aa100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
        Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=4 Masked-
        Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
        Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169

02:00.0 0280: 8086:3165 (rev 79)
        Subsystem: 8086:8110
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 51
        Memory at aa000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
        Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number d8-f2-ca-ff-ff-45-fb-6e
        Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Capabilities: [154] L1 PM Substates
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Other possible useful information:

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
- I don't think I have an SD card because there's still room to put an SD card into the socket, however I can't say with 100% certainty that the internal workings of the mini PC don't require/use an SD somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a Beelink BT3-X. Same manufacturer, exact same problem. I "solved" it by disabling SD card altogether in the BIOS.

Navigate to **Chipset** -> **SCC Configuration** and disable **SCC eMMC Support (D28:F0)**.

> This however just means that I'm unable to use the SD slot

Yeah... fortunatley I don't plan to use the slot.

Comment: I am having the same problem with a similar PC: I have a Beelink U57. It would be fine for me to disable the SD card altogether in the BIOS, yet I can't achieve this: my BIOS is completely different and there is no such option, nor anything that looks like SCC. Have you any idea what could be the right parameter I need to modify?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to 'solve' this problem by disabling the sdhci modules all together by adding them to the kernel [blacklist](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3270624/blacklisting-modules-on-linux.html) so it won't be started on boot, and then refreshing the blacklist because the old copy was still in [initramfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88301/kernel-module-blacklist-not-working)

This however just means that I'm unable to use the SD slot in the future I assume so its not a perfect fix. If anyone has a way to fix it properly, I would love to hear it!.